# Gstreamer + h264 stream from c920 + v4l2loopback not working

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, v4l2, logitech, v4l2loopback

I've been a month working in a project with cubieboard2 and the webcam logitech c920, after a lot of search and trial error I decided to use gstreamer + v4l2loopback for sending the hardware encoded h264 stream that provides the c920 to vlc and add textoverlay with this program.

The problem came when I tried to use gstreamer with v4l2loopback. If I use the raw stream from the logitech works fine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! "video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1" ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 sync=0
```

also with this it's fine

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e uvch264src device=/dev/video0 name=src auto-start=true      src.vfsrc ! queue ! video/x-raw,format=\(string\)YUY2,width=320,height=240,framerate=10/1 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 sync=0
```

But when I use the h264 stream:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e uvch264src device=/dev/video0 name=src auto-start=true src.vidsrc ! queue ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 sync=0
```

It doesn't work, outputing a "streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)"
what's curious is that program outputs different caps form the ones I've specified on the pipeline:

> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUvcH264Src:src.GstGhostPad:vfsrc: caps =
>   video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)2304, height=(int)1536,
>   pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive,
>   framerate=(fraction)2/1
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUvcH264Src:src.GstGhostPad:vfsrc.GstProxyPad:proxypad0:
>   caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)2304,
>   height=(int)1536, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1,
>   interlace-mode=(string)progressive, framerate=(fraction)2/1

I'm quite sure the problem is related with this but I don't know how to go on trying to solve this problem, any help would be very appreciated.

I'm using:

- v4l2loopback (0.8.0)
- Gstreamer 1.2.4
- cubieboard2 (arm computer)
- webcam logitech c920

Comment: Add `GST_DEBUG=3` or `GST_DEBUG=4` before your `gst-launch` to see more debug information.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, sorry for the delay I was moving from my flat this weekend and left the project a little bit aside. Here's the GST_DEBUG=4 output: http://justpaste.it/g2fr